# How to set trackball click listener for EditField

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-editfield

I want to set an listener for `EditField` so that whenever user clicks on the `EditField` (Not a touch screen) it redirects to a page and i perform some operations on it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, we cant set trackball listener for editfield. If you want it i think there is a method. Use navigationClick() method along with trackwheel events. But there are no trackball events.